# Java Spring Boot problem LoggiFailureAnalysisReporter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to Boot-Spring apparently, I mostly copy some code from youtube on this case. However, after modification, in the end, I got a message like this;
APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field postService in com.example.demo.BlogController required a bean of type 'Server.PostService' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'Server.PostService' in your configuration.

.....Any idea how to deal with this situation. Thank you for the support.
1stclass-BlogApplciation-----com.example.demo(package)
2nd-Blog Controller--------same package as BlogApplication
3rdclass-Post---entities
4rthclass-PostRepositories---Repositories

```
**package com.example.demo;  

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
  

@SpringBootApplication

public class BlogApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(BlogApplication.class, args);
}
```

}**

```
  **package com.example.demo;
  import java.util.List;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
 import Server.PostService;
 import entities.Post;
 import java.util.Date;
  @RestController
  public class BlogController {
  @Autowired
  private PostService postService;
  @GetMapping(value="/")

  public String index() {
    return "index";
    }
  @GetMapping(value="/posts")
  public List<Post>posts(){
  return postService.getAllPosts();
 
    }
  @PostMapping(value="/post")
  public void publishPost(@RequestBody Post post) {
  
   if(post.getDatecreation() == null) 
  post.setDatecreation(new Date());
      postService.insert(post);  
     }
     }**
 

  **package entities;
    import java.util.Date;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    @Entity
     public class Post {
      @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
     private Long id;
     private String title;
    private String body;
    private Date Datecreation;

    public Post() {
    
     }
    public long getId() {
    return id;
     }
    public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
    }   
    public String gettitle() {
    return title;
     }
    public void settitle(String title) {
     this.title= title;
     }
    public String getBody() {
    return body;
     }
    public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
     }
    public Date getDatecreation() {
    return Datecreation;
    }
    public void setDatecreation(Date datecreation) {
    this.Datecreation = datecreation;
    }
    }**


   **package Repositories;

   import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
   import entities.Post;
   @Repository
   public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post,Long>{
    }**
```

Comment: If you want examples for spring boot, here is some working examples: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples, https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa

Comment: Your package structure is wrong. Move everything in `com.example.demo` or make it a sub package. But `Services` and `Repositories` aren't under that package and hence aren't scanned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `BlogApplication` Class, which is the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` is in the package `com.example.demo`. That means that, by default, Spring is going to launch a Component Scan starting from that package.

The problem is that your class `PostService` and your interface `PostRepository` are not in the same package as (or in a sub-package of) `com.example.demo`, so Spring can't find them and won't automatically create these beans for you.

To correct this issue, move the packages you created inside your root package (`com.example.demo`).

You can find more information about the use of `@SpringBootApplication` [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html).

Comment: Thank you to were right man... redid again today and problem was that all should derive from com.example.demo

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

You are missing PostService class or you have imported incorrect class as Server.PostService.

try to create a service like this one:

```
@Component 
public class PostService {
    public List<Post> getAllPosts(){
     //your code
    }
}
```